# Search with 2 tables in a relationship issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm trying to create a search using 2 tables by relationship where :

1) I select all my ejecutives using 'select_tag' in my view "Policies".

2) After select an ejecutive from my table "Ejecutives" i want all the policies by ejecutive that i selected like this.

```
select* from policies where ejecutive_id = 1
select* from policies where ejecutive_id = 2
select* from policies where ejecutive_id = "the ejecutive that i selected"
```

My tables

```
 TABLE EJECUTIVES
       |id|  |name| |lastname1|
 TABLE POLICIES
       |id|  |num_police|  |ejecutive_id|
```

My models

```
class Policy < ActiveRecord::Base
   unloadable
   belongs_to :ejecutive
   has_many :policy

   def self.search(search)
    if search
      find(:all, :conditions => ["ejecutive_id LIKE ? ", "#{search}"  ] )
    else
      find(:all)
    end
   end
end

class Ejecutive < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :policies
end
```

Here is my controller

```
class PolicyManagement::PolicyController < ApplicationController
    def generate_print_ejecutive_comercial
      @ejecutives = Ejecutive.find(:all)
      @policies = Policy.search(params[:search]).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
    end
end
```

Here is my view

```
<% form_tag :controller=>"policy_management/policy",:action =>"generate_print_ejecutive_comercial", :method => 'get' do %>
    <%= select_tag "Ejecutives", options_for_select(@ejecutives.collect {|t| [t.name.to_s+" "+t.lastname1.to_s,t.id]}) %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
<% end %>

 Results
     <% @policies.each do |policy| %>
     <p> <%= policy.num_policy%> </p>
     <p> <%= policy.ejecutive.name %> </p>
     <p> <%= policy.ejecutive.last_name %> </p>
     <% end %>
     <%= will_paginate @policies %>
```

I tried this

```
 %= select_tag "Ejecutives", options_for_select(@ejecutives.collect {|t| [t.name.to_s+" "+t.lastname1.to_s,t.id]}),params[:search] %>
```

Does somebody know about this problem? I'd really appreciate help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the tag name to `search`.

```
<%= select_tag "search", options_for_select(@ejecutives.collect {|t| [t.name.to_s+" "+t.lastname1.to_s,t.id]}) %>
```

Also change the search method

```
  find(:all, :conditions => ["ejecutive_id = ? ", search.to_i  ] )
```

Comment: when user clicks the Search button in the form, it makes a request with `js` format to the app. This goes to the `generate_print_ejecutive_commercial` method in the contoller and since the request format is `js` Rails would by default render `generate_print_ejecutive_comercial.js.erb`.

Comment: OK , i tried your code but i'm not getting policies by ejecutives selected

Comment: there might be a bug, can you check if the `generate_print_ejecutive_commercial` action is called when you submit the form. You can do this by adding `puts params` in the action and see if it appears in the console where server is running.

Comment: the problem is here  <%= select_tag "Ejecutives", options_for_select(@ejecutives.collect {|t| [t.name.to_s+" "+t.lastname1.to_s,t.id]}) %> is not doing a relation is just only getting my ejecutives, do you know how to get all the policies when i select a ejecutive?

Comment: changed the answer, misunderstood the question first time. The issue is select tag name, it should be `search`